# IK controller won't bend joints but only moves the entire arm

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

The arm from the bottom has three bones. Upper. Lower. And hand. With the bigger one being the IK controller. And the one from the side is the pole.

[image]

And when I tried to move the controller this is what happens

[image]

(As I was taking a screenshot. I found out that the controller is limited to only move in the y local axis of the bone chain, But I don't know how'd that happen or how can I remove it.)

(also is there a way to make the ik controller work without bending the bones)

Comment: The problem is that your IK chain is completely straight.  Give it a bend to tell Blender which way you want it to go.

Comment: is it possible to do it without bending the bone

Comment: No, you need to bend the bone-- although you can do so in edit, in pose, with a driver, or with a constraint.

Comment: how much do I have to bend the bone? I want it to be straight as possible.

Comment: It's gonna bend anyways-- that's what IK does. But, you don't need much bend.  Just try it out.

Comment: I bend each bone that's above the IK about 0.0025 and it worked. Thanks a lot!